# XUnit unit tests for a method with an interface as a return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit, xunit.net

I have a method in my service class called `ClassifyImage`. And this method's return type is an Interface.

```
public interface ICreatePrediction
{
     Task<IMLResponseObject> ClassifyImage(IFormFile file, int age, string sex, string location, string imageId);
}
```

I want to call this method and define a result, in my test class. I used `A.CallTo` to do that.

```
public class GetClassificationHandlerTests
{
    //rest of the code

    private readonly Mock<IMLResponseObject> _customResponse;

    public GetClassificationHandlerTests(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        //rest of the code

        _customResponse = new Mock<IMLResponseObject>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Image_Scan_With_All_InterfaceResponses_Successful_Returns_Valid_Output()
    {
         A.CallTo(() => _iCreatePrediction.ClassifyImage(_customInput.file, _customInput.age, _customInput.sex, _customInput.location, _customInput.imageId))
                .Returns(_customResponse);
         
        //The result should be of the type IMLResponseObject
        result.ShouldBeOfType<IMLResponseObject>();

         //rest of the code
     }
}
```

Note that `_customInput` is defined in the code.

First of all, I need to know that Is this a correct approach?

Then, in the above code, I'm getting an error saying,
`'IReturnValueArgumentValidationConfiguration<Task<IMLResponseObject>>' does not contain a definition for 'Returns' and the best extension method overload 'ValueTaskReturnValueConfigurationExtensions.Returns<Mock<IMLResponseObject>>`,

and it's coming from the line `A.CallTo(() => _iCreatePrediction.ClassifyImage.....`

Any help or tips are highly appreciated on this matter.

Comment: Struggling to reproduce this. I'm guessing the `Mock` class comes from the `Moq` nuget package? And `ITestOutputHelper` comes from the `Xunit.Abstractions` namespace? I've created an empty `IMLResponseObject` class just to resolve the build errors which reference it, and added `using System.Threading.Tasks` to resolve the build errors which reference `Task`. But I still get build errors for `A`, `_customResponse` and `result` not existing, and I'm sure I'll get another one for `_iCreatePrediction` not existing once the compiler can get that far.

Comment: Can you edit the code in your question to a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which isn't dependent on other code which isn't shared as part of the question and which probably isn't part of the problem?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you should be trying to mock the `_iCreatePrediction.ClassifyImage` method rather than trying to make it return a mock of its return value, but without a MRE that I can build, run and see the errors for myself, that's at best just a guess.